# Autowire annotation in JAX-RS and Spring

Tags: spring, jax-rs

I am trying to add REST support to my Spring 3 + Hibernate application.

I have created the REST support using the wizard from Netbeans, at it has put a @Autowire annotation (not @autowired) above my Resource class. Getting the @Autowire annotation from Spring causes the error

```
 incompatible types
found   : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire
required: java.lang.annotation.Annotation
```

Getting @Autowire from JAX-RS should be only for Spring 2.5 as far as I understand from [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1858). I get the following error if I include it, which I think is related to Spring 2.5 being loaded:

```
    SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception 
parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/
Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
```

Could someone point me on how to add this annotation, and make JAX-RS work with Spring? Also, I was using a SessionFactory and the autogenerated code refers to a entityManagerFactory in the applicationcontext. Can those be used interchangingly?

PS: Allow me to say that I hate Java EE with a passion so far in my three week journey with the platform, major stumbling blocks at every level, sorry for the rant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Autowire`.  [The 'Netbeans REST wizard' looks like it would be using `com.sun.jersey.api.spring.Autowire` (last image, very bottom of page)](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html), and from your message above, you are using [`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.2/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowire.html) which appears to be an `Enum` used in Spring 2.0.

From what I can tell, this may be a specific thing to Spring 2.0 anyways.  Perhaps you should take a look at doing the REST JAX-RS stuff yourself [(using Jersey)](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html), as it is not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I decided to implement it myself since it wasn't worth the headache.